# IMAP server implementation in Ruby EventMachine

Tags: ruby, imap, eventmachine

I am looking for IMAP server protocol implementation in Ruby EventMachine.

Can someone advice a library or share some source code?

Comment: That's a hell of an undertaking. IMAP is not a small protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any existing IMAP server in ruby but depending on your needs there is another approach you could use: setup a full fledged imap C server but instead of binding it to an external port you bind it on localhost and put an eventmachine process between it and the clients. This way you can intercept/modify commands you care about and let the other pass through.

Without knowing more about what you want to do it is hard to give a more relevant answer.